# pip and apt-get install commands

Tags: apt, pip

I would like to ask what the command pip does? Does it install a new application? If the answer is 'yes', so why do we have to type "apt-get install" after using "pip"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` installs packages for and apps written in Python which are published to [PyPI, the Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

`apt-get` installs software from  Ubuntu and third-party repositories. Many `pip`-installable packages have an equivalent `apt` package. For example, you can install the `cherrypy` Python module using either `pip` or `apt-get`:

```
pip install cherrypy
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get install python-cherrypy
```

Also, no, you *don't* have to type `apt-get install` after `pip install`.